# Check if HTML row text box are empty and select index is zero except last row

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code below creates a query to insert data where I'm checking if:

Any text box value is not empty or any selected index is not "0" except last row

My below code does that but the problem is:

It goes to the else condition if the first rows value is filled and prints the data of the first row.

It should loop inside until all the values of the text boxes are filled and the selected value is not "0" except last row.

[Demo Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szkp0Lwq/4/)

HTML:

```
<form id="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey1">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse1">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <select name="select2">
                    <option>No Match</option>
                    <option value="1">Test</option>
                    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey2">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse2">
            </td>
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <select name="select2">
                    <option>No Match</option>
                    <option value="1">Test</option>
                    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>skip row
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="skip row">
            </td>
            <td>skip row
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="skip row">
            </td>
            </td>
            <td>skip row
                <select name="select2">
                    <option>No Match</option>
                    <option value="1">Test</option>
                    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="Get();" />
<div id="data"></div>
```

JS:

```
function Get() {
    var html = '';
    var arr = [];
   var valid = true;
$('tr').each(function(index, me) {
  if(index < $('tr').length - 1 && valid) {
    var inputs = $('input', me);
    inputs.each(function(index, me) {
      if($(me).val().length == 0)
        valid = false;
    });
    var selects = $('select :selected', me);
    selects.each(function(index, me) {
      if($(me)[0].selectedIndex == 0)
        valid = false;
    });

      if(!valid)

      {
      alert("null");

      }

      else{

       arr.push('("' + inputs[0].value + '","' + inputs[1].value + '","' + selects[0].text + '")');
        alert();
      }
  }
});

    html = 'INSERT INTO demo (xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) VALUES ' + arr.join(',') + ';';
    $('#data').html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Table has tr's children, so you can capture them with jquery children function.

Since it's returns an array you can know the length by this way:

```
$('table').children().length
```

Then you must use the **For** loop instead of **Each**, varaying **from 0 to  $('table').children().length - 1** . With this way everything you do inside the loop won't count for the last child.

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you help me updating my post i tried above ma be am going wrong it dint work

Answer (score 0):

First I would say obtain the `<tr>` before looping. That way you can splice the last indices.

The defect is actually in the `selects` each. Looks like the option is the "selected" and therefore `$(me)[0].selectedIndex` is invalid.

https://jsfiddle.net/jdgiotta/fhdra9mq/

Comment: it check s if the first row  value if the condition don't meat then it gives the out put as expected fine till hear but on second one as the first one is correct that goes to the else condition and prints the out put that should not happen it should loop and check until all the text box value if filled and the select index is not expect last row

Comment: If you won't want the loop to break then remove the `if(!value)` from within the loop. https://jsfiddle.net/jdgiotta/fhdra9mq/8/